# Return multiple mock objects from a mocked factory function which returns std::unique_ptr

Tags: c++, googletest, googlemock

How to return multiple mock objects from a mocked factory function which returns std::unique_ptr?

`Return(ByMove(...))` cannot be used to return multiple times.

Trying to work from this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/70751684/3545094

I came up with this:

```
class MyType {
 public:
  virtual ~MyType() {}
};

class MyTypeMock : public MyType {};

class MyFactory {
 public:
  virtual ~MyFactory() {}
  virtual std::unique_ptr<MyType> create() = 0;
};

class MyFactoryMock : public MyFactory {
 public:
  MOCK_METHOD0(create, std::unique_ptr<MyType>());
};

TEST(SomeTest, MyTestCase) {
  MyFactoryMock myFactoryMock;
  EXPECT_CALL(myFactoryMock, create())
    .Times(3)
    .WillRepeatedly([]() { return std::make_unique<MyTypeMock>(); });

  (void)myFactoryMock.create();
  (void)myFactoryMock.create();
  (void)myFactoryMock.create();
}
```

Problem is conversion from lambda to Action it seems:

```
/.../my_test.cc: In member function ‘virtual void SomeTest_MyTestCase_Test::TestBody()’:
/.../my_test.cc:122:111: error: cannot convert ‘SomeTest_MyTestCase_Test::TestBody()::<lambda()>’ to ‘const testing::Action<std::unique_ptr<MyType>()>&’
  122 |   EXPECT_CALL(myFactoryMock, create()).Times(3).WillRepeatedly([]() { return std::make_unique<MyTypeMock>(); });
      |                                                                                                               ^
In file included from /.../googletest/1.8.0-57/include/gmock/gmock-generated-function-mockers.h:43,
                 from /.../googletest/1.8.0-57/include/gmock/gmock.h:61,
                 from /.../my_test.h:15,
                 from /.../my_test.cc:12: /.../googletest/1.8.0-57/include/gmock/gmock-spec-builders.h:1008:53: note:   initializing argument 1 of ‘testing::internal::TypedExpectation<F>& testing::internal::TypedExpectation<F>::WillRepeatedly(const testing::Action<F>&) [with F = std::unique_ptr<MyType>()]’
 1008 |   TypedExpectation& WillRepeatedly(const Action<F>& action) {
      |                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~
```

What am I missing?

Comment: What comilper are you using? And what is the version of the compiler, c++ standard and gtest library? Your code compiles without any problem [here](https://godbolt.org/z/4nnYzoYq9).

Comment: gtest/gmock 1.10 solves issue, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Stepping gtest/gmock to 1.10 solves this issue.